# Is there a way to modify the Eclipse Welcome Screen

Tags: eclipse

I have an eclipse portable edition. I was wondering if its possible to modify the welcome screen with our own links etc.
The welcome screen that I am referring to is: 
[image: Eclipse Welcome Screen]

I would like to add my own links and images in this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an entire [infrastructure](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_intro.htm) set up for customization of the welcome screen.